# Why is My Lighting Creating a Triangle on the Ground?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

More trouble going through the Roland Hess Blender Foundations book.  When I create the indoor scene in Blender, I get an odd light triangle on the ground.  I don't know why this is happening.  Help is appreciated!!

The blend: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zg96duw8av52st3/Flower%20019.blend

The last render: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u9mldvxhxh79fc/Blend%2019.png?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your sun lamp near and far *Clipping* values.

Adjust the *Clip Start* and *Clip End* values for the `Spot.008` lamp that is acting as sun.

Comment: Thanks!  For those with the same issue, expand the clipping to correct the issue.